# opencart 2: choosing MySQLi or mPDO on install, which one is preferred?

Tags: mysqli, pdo, opencart2.x

During the installation of opencart, it offers to choose between two options MySQLi or mPDO. Which one would be more recommended for better overall performance. Are there any issue further down the road with either one?

Comment: As mPDO seems to suffer from some of [One's first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes), you better stick to mysqli. While vanilla PDO would be the best choice, if available.

Comment: Thank you. I think this can qualify as an answer though.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend going with MSQLI. I've always installed it that way and never had any problems